# Where is Google Play billing package?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

Following [billing integration](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html) tutorial, I should now install Google Play billing package from SDK manager (see figure 1). However, in my SDK manager I don't have this package listed  under Extras nor anywhere else.

Where can I get this billing example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also face this problem this morning but I finally solved it.

To solve it, update your ADT plugin to the latest version,
you should able to see the packages then.

After updating the ADT plugin, you may also need to update installed tools to the latest version to ensure you existing projects can run normally.

Answer (score 2):

Via SDK Manager, I updated Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform Tools, re-ran SDK Manager, and the billing package then appeared under Extras as expected.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, might help others!